# Difference between template structure creation in C++

Tags: c++

What is the difference between

```
#define Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE)                                        \
    template <>                                                         \
    struct QMetaTypeId< TYPE >                                          \
    {                                                                   \
       ...                                                              \
    };                                                                  \
```

and

```
#define Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TYPE)                                        \
    template <TYPE>                                                     \
    struct QMetaTypeId                                                  \
    {                                                                   \
       ...                                                              \
    };                                                                  \
```

?

Comment: In the first, you are declaring a specialization from the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one defines a template class called `QMetaTypeId` with the template parameters provided for `TYPE`. Once this has been declared, specializations of `QMetaTypeId` can be defined for different template arguments.

The first one defines a specialization for the `QMetaTypeId` template class for when the template arguments are `TYPE`. It assumes that a template class already exists which can me specialized.

An example of each:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE2(typename T) //primary template
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE1(int) //specialization for int

QMetaType<int> a; //uses the specialization
QMetaType<float> b; //uses the primary template
```

The second version seems very odd, whereas the first version might be used to make it easy for users of a library to declare specializations of a library template class for their own types.

Comment: You could add a link to http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

Answer (score 1):

First is [explicit template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). Second is [template definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

Quote from the documentation:

> **Explicit specialization** can only appear at namespace scope, in the same namespace as the primary template (or in the nearest enclosing namespace if the primary is a member template), and it **has to appear after the non-specialized template declaration**.